# Get data at address from Cheat Engine with python

Tags: python, cheat-engine

I've used Cheat Engine to get an Address and RealAddress for the X coordinate of my player in a game; Sea of Thieves. Unfortunately, the game crashes when I try to find the pointer by methods described online (ie clicking "Find out what access this address"). Since the Address and RealAddress don't seem to change (SoTGame.exe+699FE50 and 7FF6EA32FE50, respectively), is there a way to access the value at this address?

I'd like to use something like ReadWriteMemory (example code from the Git ReadMe w/my adaptations):

```
from ReadWriteMemory import ReadWriteMemory

rwm = ReadWriteMemory()

process = rwm.get_process_by_name('SoTGame.exe')
process.open()

#health_pointer= process.get_pointer(0x004e4dbc, offsets=[0xf4])
x_pointer = process.get_pointer(0x699FE50)

#health = process.read(health_pointer)
x = process.read(x_pointer)

print({'x': x})
```

Printing currently returns 0 while cheat engine is showing a very different number.

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the address with offset to the module entry.

Calling `get_process_by_name` will return the pointer to the process base in memory, but here you want to offset this pointer to the module entry of the process.
The `0x699FE50` is your offset from the module entry, `'SoTGame.exe'`, hence finding and adding your module entry `module_base` (usually 0x00400000) will result in the correct address in memory.

In your case, `get_pointer(module_base + 0x699FE50)` should do the trick.